# PayPal Third PartyShopping Cart and REST APIs

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart

Do PayPal's REST Api support Third Party shopping carts the way their classic APIs do?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, take a look at this info about getting a token for 3rd party users:  [Obtaining a User's Consent](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#obtain-users-consent).

Comment: Curious who down-voted my correct answer, and why..??